# Display QStandardItemModel in a QML TableView

Tags: qt, model, qml

I'm trying to display a QStandardItemModel subclass with the Qt Controls TableView in QML.

The model class looks like this:

```
class CommandModel : public QStandardItemModel {

Q_OBJECT

public:
    CommandModel(QObject *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void startProcess(); 
    // and other thing that only fetch data and use appendRow()
    // to add the data to the model.
};
```

The model is currently a table of two columns (the command name and its description).

I use QQmlApplicationEngine and QQuickWindow to display the QML.

The QML code is below:

```
TableView {
    id: tableview
    model: commandModel

    TableViewColumn {
        title: qsTr("Command")
        role: "name"
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        title: qsTr("Description")
        role: "description"
    }
}
```

The TableView gets displayed, lines are shown (if i'm not mistaken, there's the right number of lines) but they're only blanks lines.

The model is passed to the QML context before it's has finished loading. I don't think that it's the problem since i first see an empty table and then a table with many empty lines.

I don't know how to define which column correspond to which role.

Any help is welcomed and thanked.

EDIT: the code can be found here: https://github.com/martinqt/Symfony2Helper

EDIT2: I get a randomly working first column by re-implementing roleNames (or so it seems since it's randomly weird).

EDIT2.1: In fact, it's the setItemRoleNames() that made the trick of displaying the first column.

EDIT3: the problem more looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270969/using-a-qabstracttablemodel-with-a-qml-tableview-display-ony-the-1st-column?rq=1). I'm going to try and see if it solves it.

**Solution**: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270969/using-a-qabstracttablemodel-with-a-qml-tableview-display-ony-the-1st-column?rq=1) solve the whole problem. Implement data() and roleNames(). (Don't have to use an enum if you don't want to).

Comment: I haven't overloaded it. I did a try, putting a qDebug in there but it wasn't called (other qDebug did produced output). I tried to implement row and column count but they didn't seemed to be called either. I'm not using QAbstractItemModel. Quoting the doc `QStandardItemModel implements the QAbstractItemModel interface`. Maybe I did it wrong, I haven't much experience with Qt models in C++. If you think that is the cause of the problem, what should I put in data?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, the problem come from those lines:

```
roles[0] = "name";
roles[0] = "desc";
```

As you can see, you're first setting "name" as the role 0 and then override that value with the "desc" name. Try changing it so that they have different indexes.

```
roles[0] = "name";
roles[1] = "desc";
```

You should now have the name working. You second problem come from the fact that you are registering the "desc" role, but using the "description" role in qml. So modify either the role name in c++ or qml so that they match.

```
roles[0] = "name";
roles[1] = "description";
```

Comment: I pushed this commit by mistake. I committed it however because strangely enough, this doesn't override the 0 value: I have two columns with the name while if I put only one line, I get only the name. When I try what should be the right thing to do (your last code), I only have the name column displaying. I have tested that the model does have the data for the description column and they are correctly present. I tried different indexes (even -1), swapped lines, changed role names in both C++ and QML and the second column still refuse to display. (never managed to display the second in any way)