# QML Output matrix

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, model-view

I have a matrix

```
QVector<QVector<double>> A;
```

that I want to output and edit.
In QWidgets I put this matrix into QAbstractTableModel subclass and set this as a model for QTableView.
In qml this doesn't seem to work with TableView.

As I [understood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270969/using-a-qabstracttablemodel-with-a-qml-tableview-only-displays-the-1st-column%22%22), for fixed size matrices I can explicitly write roles for each column:

```
TableViewColumn {
        role: "first" // "second", "third" etc.
}
```

And then for each role return corresponding column from QAbstractTableModel::data(...).

But what if matrix dimensions are computed in runtime? What is the best way to work with such matrices in qml?

Comment: I guess you should notify the table with [insertColumns](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#insertColumns), [removeColumns](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#removeColumns) if your data source has changed.

Comment: @folibis: I don't think that will do the trick, as, afaik, QML does not care for model columns. I think you should expose a property, e.g. `roleNames` which you then use as a `Repeater` to create `TableViewColumn`s with `role: modelData`

Answer (score 0):

> Note: *Might be hacky but works*

I have not worked with a `QAbstractTableModel` and QML so far, but to my understanding, QML does not care for columns, so a `ListModel` should be a sufficient subsitution for an example:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQml 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: myWindow
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600
    color: 'white'

    ListModel {
        id: lv
        property var roleNames: ['role1', 'role2']
        ListElement { role1: 'a'; role2: 'b' }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: tm
        property var roleNames: [ 'myID', 'age', 'name']
        ListElement { myID:  1; name: 'Egon';    age: 15 }
        ListElement { myID:  2; name: 'Herbert'; age: 21 }
        ListElement { myID:  3; name: 'Jan';     age: 11 }
        ListElement { myID:  4; name: 'Dieter';  age: 23 }
        ListElement { myID:  5; name: 'Ulrich';  age:  6 }
        ListElement { myID:  6; name: 'Hans';    age: 45 }
        ListElement { myID:  7; name: 'Frieder'; age: 31 }
        ListElement { myID:  8; name: 'Gerd';    age: 28 }
    }

    TableView {
        id: tv
        model: lv
        anchors.fill: parent
        Instantiator {
            model: tv.model ? tv.model.roleNames : 0
            delegate: TableViewColumn {
                title: modelData
                role: modelData
                Component.onCompleted: tv.addColumn(this)
                Component.onDestruction: tv.removeColumn(0)
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: tv.model = (tv.model === lv ? tm : lv)
    }
}
```

By adding a second model, I create a sufficient and accordingly configured amount of `TableViewColumn`s that I then add to the `TableView` utilizing a `Instantiator` (as `TableViewColumn` is no `Item` as it seems).

A problem that arrises here, is that I don't find a way to access the column index, I need to call `tv.removeColumn` with the proper index. But in this case, where I always replace the whole model, this is no problem as long I delete all columns, one after another by always removing the first with `tv.removeColumn(0)`. I will still get a error

> `Error: Invalid attempt to destroy() an indestructible object`

as this method tries to invoke `destroy()` on a object that is not created with JS, but this is no problem. The `Instantiator` will delete it right after.

So: Though there is a error message, this will work, as long as you completely reset the model of the `Instantiator` everytime there is a change.